# Continuous scrolling problem in TexShop preview

Tags: preview, macos, latex

I am using TexShop on Mac OS. Everything works fine, the pdf is generated and I can do continuous scrolling. However, when I view the pdf in

(a) full screen mode and (b) zoom a page of this pdf,

I get stuck with the same page and there is no continuous scrolling possible.

Comment: @benwiggy, In TeXShop, Cmd 1 switches between the tex editor and the pdf (preview).

Comment: I'm not using TexShop but maybe there is a way to see the current view? (maybe in the menu bar > View?)

Answer (score 0):

After you go into full screen mode, go to the Preview menu and choose Display Format -> MultiPage or Double MultiPage. That works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me when I zoom a page. But if I don't zoom, it works fine.

Comment: @seeker: How are you zooming the page? If I use a pinch/spread gesture on a touchpad, I can continue to scroll. Same with setting the scaling in the toolbar. Ultimately, you may need to report this as a bug to TexShop's developer.